# perl get linux cached memory number

Tags: linux, perl, caching, memory

I'm writing a perl script and I would really like to get the amount of cached memory currently being used on my linux box. When you run "`free -m`", you get this output:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           496        322        173          0         33        106
-/+ buffers/cache:        183        312
Swap:         1023         25        998
```

The number under "cached" is the value I want. I've been using [Linux::SysInfo](http://search.cpan.org/~vpit/Linux-SysInfo-0.13/lib/Linux/SysInfo.pm),which helps me get a lot of useful information about my box, but seems to be lacking cached memory. Does anyone know of another module or elegant way in perl to get the amount of cached memory on my machine? I know that I could get it by running this:

```
my $val = `free -m`;
```

And then running regex on `val`, but I'd prefer another solution if one exists. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you *only* want a Perl solution, or if any command line solution will be acceptable. Just in case, here is a simple [AWK](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) solution:

```
free -m | awk '/^Mem:/{print $NF}'
```

that will print the number you are interested in.

You could assign it to some shell variable if that was necessary:

```
$ c_val=`free -m | awk '/^Mem:/{print $NF}'`
$ echo $c_val
```

will display the value to verify.

*Explanation of `awk` command*:

`/^Mem:/` searches for a line that contains the string `Mem:` at the start. If it is found it prints the *last* item on that line which is the number we are interested in. In awk the line is split into fields based on white space. `$0` is the whole line, `$1` the first field, `$2` the second etc. The number of fields per line is given by the pre-defined awk `NF` variable, so we can access the last field on the line with `$NF`.

We could have also used this awk command:

```
awk 'NR==2{print $NF}'
```

which makes use of the pre-defined awk `NR` variable that contains the current line number. In this case we print the last item (field) on the 2nd line.

Comment: Could you explain how this works to me? I get free -m is piped into the awk command, but it's the awk part that I don't get.

Comment: @srchulo I added an explanation and it made me think of an alternative way to use awk for this too. You could pick one that suits you better.

Comment: @srchulo Thank you .. `awk` is pretty awesome for these sort of things. If you are curious, here are some [awk one-liners](http://www.pement.org/awk/awk1line.txt) .. there are more if you want to google after you check this out.

Answer (score 6):

Running `strace free -m` show that it is using `/proc/mem`:

> open("/proc/meminfo", O_RDONLY)         = 3

`cat /proc/meminfo` confirms that this contains the information you're looking for.

Comment: sorry, can you explain your solution a little bit more? How do I get cached memory out of that answer?

Comment: @srchulo You'll see it has a list of Key: value pairs - you can do what `free` does and read that list directly to find the things you care about.

Answer (score 0):

You can read it from `/proc/meminfo`:

```
perl -ne's/^Cached: *//&&print' /proc/meminfo
```

or directly only value in kB:

```
perl -anE'/^Cached/&&say$F[1]' /proc/meminfo
```